# Outlook 2013 / Exchange 2013 Contacts are overwritten

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-2013

We are running an Exchange 2013 Server on premises with Outlook 2013 Clients.

One of our users is facing a strange problem:

His contact's mail addresses and phone numbers are overwritten automatically, so now several contacts have the same mail address.

He changed it back manually once (we assumed pebcak), but now the same thing happened again with even more contacts and multiple addresses that took over the original ones.

The addresses that are now in place are both internal and external addresses.

I did *New-MailboxRepairRequest -DetectOnly* with all CorruptionTypes for his Mailbox, but it shows 0 corruptions.

wth?

Comment: Does the user have a mobile phone at all?

Comment: Yes, Android and iOS

Comment: I have seen this before, where it was the phone that was overwriting everything. The only option was to remove the contacts from the mailbox completely (clean them up and then put them in to a sub directory - so outside of the "Contacts" folder). Then remove the ActiveSync partnership and accounts from the phone. Put everything back and then resync.

Comment: Wow, OK. iOS is known to mess with Exchange in some cases, but this one was new to me.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't have access to the User's account until next year. I'll let you know how it went then.

Comment: We deleted the user's account from all mobile devices and there hasen't been any trouble in two weeks now. I guess that's the answer. Thanks Sembee!